# PreferenceFragmentCompat won't change color when change theme and recreate activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-appcompat, android-preferences

I'm using PreferenceFragmentCompat for preferences and when I change theme preference using ListPreference to a dark theme and recreate activity text stays dark and becomes not visible. If I reopen this fragment text becomes white, but it returns to black color on orientation change

**Here is my styles:**

```
     <style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/preferenceLight</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondaryText</item>

</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/preferenceDark</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primaryText</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryTextDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondaryText</item>

</style>

<style name="preferenceLight" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondaryText</item>
</style>

<style name="preferenceDark" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryTextDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primaryTextDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondaryText</item>
</style>
```

**and fragment**

```
    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

private lateinit var advertisePreferences: AdvertisePreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    advertisePreferences = AdvertisePreferences(context!!)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.settings)
    preferenceManager.sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    preferenceManager.sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
}

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences, rootKey)
}

override fun onPreferenceTreeClick(preference: Preference): Boolean {

    when(preference.key){

    }

    return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference)
}

override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) {

    when(key){
        getString(R.string.theme_key) -> {
            activity?.recreate()
        }
    }
}

    }
```

Comment: Where are you using `setTheme()`?

Comment: When activity is created, before setContentView. In other fragments theme applied as it should be

Comment: Try  to call `setTheme()` before `activity?.recreate()`

Comment: Same result, text is black on black background

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was bug in library. It now fixed in *androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha02*